# Help making a buck converter to step down 53 VDC to 48 VDC - max 300W

Tags: buck

I need to step down from 53V to anywhere between 36V to 48V. Because of space constrains, I want to build a DIY solution. I have searched a lot but i cannot find any schematic/project that meets my requirements ant that i could follow (I am a relatively inexperienced DIYer).
Can anyone point me in the direction of a project/schematic that i could use? thanks!

use case:

- Subwoofer power amp. The built in PSU provides 53VDC. I need to change the stock amplifier and the amplifier i want to use cannot accept more than 48V. Any voltage from 36V to 48V will work. My preference is to stay as high as possible withing this range.

Requirements:

- The normal power consumption will be between 6 and 20 W. But it should be capable to stand peaks up to 300 W that will be seldom, maybe never, reached.
- Efficiency as high as possible: the subwoofer is sealed. The amp plate is metallic and acts as heat sink. Overheating was not a problem at all with the stock PSU and amp, so i think it will not be a problem after my modification, but to stay on the safe side i prefer the buck converter to be as efficient as possible.
- I prefer to build my own PCB to make it fit to the space available and with the existing screws.

Comment: Buy a 48 V power supply? Crack open the existing one and adjust down the output voltage?

Comment: What is the anticipated range of input supply voltages. It can't be (never is) fixed at 53 volts so, how low can it droop and how high can it peak. What peak current do you want the circuit to be able to deliver? What is an acceptable maximum level of output ripple? Are their any requirements for EMI compatibility or, switching frequencies that must be avoided?

Comment: If it's a switching PSU you can adjust the voltage by changing a resistor value, it's close enough.

Comment: TI has a ["Power Designer" tool](https://webench.ti.com/power-designer/). As an inexperienced DIYer, what chip packages are you able to solder?

Comment: @Andyaka the PSU supplies 53V. I don't have the possibility to check how much it will drop under load but 53V is too much for my amp, so i need to bring it down a bit anyways. Current: worst case scenarion 300W at 36V : ca. 8 amps. I am sure i could do with less. Ripple within reason but i am not too concerned, the amp has some fileters in the input. I don't think switching frequency will be a problem.

Comment: @bobflux: i wish i knew how to modify the stock PSU to deliver 48V, but i have no idea. The problem is that it is partially covered with resin to avoid vibrations and is difficult for me to reverse engineer

Comment: @CL. i have soldered QFN40 packages, i am comfortable soldering SMD, no problem. Edit: eh, the power desiger tool looks great, thanks!

Comment: Which parts are covered in resin? If you have access to the voltage divider to the control loop, you should have everything you need.

Comment: @winny unfortunately most of it is buried in white stuff. But thank you for the suggestion because actually one key part that is accessible is a TL494 (diodes incorporated AZ494AP-E1) so i thought that i might get some sort of control on the output voltage through it... (?). I measured the square wave on the outputs C1 and C2 and i see they are in push pull mode with a duty cycle of 83.6% at a frequency of 27.7kHz. I thought that i can decrease a bit the duty cycle and get a lower output voltage.

Comment: But if i understand it well what controls the duty cycle is the voltage in pin 4 (DTC), but that pin reads only 2.2mV....?? what could i do to the 494 to see if it changes the output voltage of the PSU?

Comment: You’ll want to dig up the voltage divider. Most probably on the secondary side, close to an optocoupler and a TL431.

Comment: got it! (i think) i measure 10kOhm between DTC and GND and 12.6kOhm between DTC and ref (5V). That means that voltage at DTC should be 2.2V, that translates into 66% dead time. i measured 83.6% duty, the inverse 16.4% x2 = ca 33% -> compatible with the measured voltage divider. If i increase slightly the voltage at DTC (adding a resistor between DTC and ref, that is pretty accessible without having to dig any white stuff) should increase the dead time and hence reduce the output voltage of the PSU? any chances for this to work?

Comment: ok, i soldered a 100K resistor between pins DTC and ref of the TL494. The objective being changing the duty cycle of the outputs and see if this changes the output voltage.  The resistance between the pins was now 11.28 kOhm (vs 12.6) and the duty cycle indeed changed to 91.9%, that is ca 18%. However, the PSU still outputs the same 53.3V.... well, bad luck, will have to find the voltage divider as @winny indicated... now i wonder that the TL494 is doing there

Comment: smps duty cycle will not do much unless it is adjusted to be extremely low. An SMPS achieves voltage 'regulation' by repeatedly turning on and off its switching circuitry, with an output capacitor to help smooth this out to an acceptable level. could you provide a schematic of how this is wired together?

Comment: dont have a schematic unfortunately. But i have found there is WS3252 PWM controller connected to the auxiliray transformer. Will give it a try there.